# Fremantle players to have played a grand final

Tags: trivia, australian-rules-football

The commentators mentioned that Danyle Pearce was one of 2 Fremantle players to have previously played a grand final (being with Port Adelaide) before 2013 September 27. Who was the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zac Dawson, previously played 3 grand finals with St Kilda

Comment: And, obviously, none of them were a win. 2 losses and a draw, now 3 losses and a draw. Not a great record.